# React-pdf still loading when file is loaded in Syncfusion Tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, tabs, syncfusion

I am using a Syncfusion Tab to show many types of file depending of the tab.
A type of file that I want to show is the PDF type.
Unfortunately, unlike all the other types that I tried to show, this one is blocking me a bit.

I use react-pdf (and I don't want to use anything else) to show the pdf, and I load the file when the right tab is selected. If we change tab the file is emptied. I use useQuery to do my requests to my server and to get the file from the database. I can print the file in the console but for some reason, in the Tab Component, the react-pdf is stuck on the loading state.

I tried to replicate the same thing with only the react-pdf component and a button that calls useQuery to retrieve the file, and it works nicely, the PDF is shown, but in the Tab Component it doesn't.

My code loooks like :

The useQuery

```js
const { status, data, error, isFetching, refetch } = useQuery(['facture', id], async () => {
     const data = await getUniqueCassandraFile(id)
     setFile(data.rows[0].file)
     return data.rows[0].file
}, {
     enabled: false,
     refetchOnWindowFocus: false
})
```

The renderPdf function is in another file, along the other render function depending of the type, the file parameter is a state from the parent component, state that is being updated by the useQuery result(in the parent). The query is refectched every time we select a new tab (the selecting event) :

```js
export const renderPdf = (id, file) => {
    if(!file){
        return waiting(id)
    }
    return (
        <div key={id} className='file_container'>
            <Document file={`data:application/pdf;base64,${file}`} style={{height:50+'vh'}}>
                <Page size="A4" pageNumber={1} className="pdfFacture">
                </Page>
            </Document>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The TabComponent :

```js
<div className="control-section tab-control-section">
   {chosenItem === -1 ? emptyDiv : 
   <TabComponent overflowMode="Scrollable" id="defaultTab" selecting={selecting} 
   selectedItem={chosenItem}>
      <TabItemsDirective>
      {
         header.map((item, index) => {
            return <TabItemDirective presentation={true} key={index} header={item} 
               content={{
                  template: tabContent, 
                  data: {content: content[index], type: item.type, id: item.id}}}/>
               })
            }
            </TabItemsDirective>
         </TabComponent>
      }
 </div>
```

And the TabContent template to create each tab :

```js
const tabContent = (data) => {
   return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
             isFetching ? emptyDiv :
             switchRender(data.id, data.type, file))}}>
   </div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the file in tab selecting event based on the shared details. So, we suggest you to load the file in tab selected event instead of selecting event to resolve the reported issue. Since, selected event will be triggered once the content in rendered in DOM.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/api/tab#selected